# PHP 5 second countdown (CLI, not JavaScript)

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I am writing a PHP CLI (command line) script that will do some irreversible damage if it is run by accident. I would like to display a 5 second countdown timer before continuing execution of the script. How can I do this with PHP?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to prompt for confirmation, rather than wait? What if the person runs it then looks away for a few seconds?

Comment: Is this a system level function it is going to perform that could be destructive?

Comment: This won't answer your question, but the second I opened your question, "The Final Countdown" began playing on this Internet Radio station I was listening to.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jK-NcRmVcw

Comment: As an alternative to @jnpcl, I would stop and print a message if a certain option wasn't given, e.g. `--force`.

Comment: @DarkDust: I would use that as an additional safeguard, certainly not on its own.

Comment: @jnpcl would you mind providing an example of how to implement that?

Comment: care to elaborate on the "will do some irreversible damage" part, since I'm not sure I want to participate in that

Comment: @Gordon haha, it's just affecting some records in my database.

Comment: @Andrew: No idea, never messed with PHP CLI.

Comment: @jnpcl: I've tried to implement a "stop and wait for command to continue" script, but PHP would not always stop when I told it to stop. So I gave up on it because it was unreliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add my two cents, here's how you can add a confirmation prompt.

```
<?php

echo "Continue? (Y/N) - ";

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
if ($response != 'Y') {
   echo "Aborted.\n";
   exit;
}

$seconds = 5;

for ($i = $seconds; $i > 0; --$i) {
   echo $i;
   usleep(250000);
   echo '.';
   usleep(250000);
   echo '.';
   usleep(250000);
   echo '.';
   usleep(250000);
}

echo " Running NOW\n";
// run command here
```

(You have to type 'Y' then hit Enter.)

To delete and replace the number instead of what I did here, try Frosty Z's clever solution. Alternatively, you can get fancy using ncurses. See [this tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1083).

Answer (score 13):

Don't do a countdown. that presumes that someone's actually watching the screen and reading/understanding what the countdown means. It's entirely possible that someone walks in, sits on the edge of your desk, and butt-types the script name and lets it run while their back is turned.

Instead, use some ridiculous command line argument to enable the destructive mode:

```
$ php nastyscript.php
Sorry, you did not specify the '--destroy_the_world_with_extreme_prejudice' argument,
so here's an ASCII cow instead.

         (__)
         (oo)
  /-------\/ Moooooo
 / |     ||
*  ||----||
   ^^    ^^

$ php nastyscript.php --destroy_the_world_with_extreme_prejudice
Initiating Armageddon...
*BOOM*
ATH0++++ NO CARRIER
```

---

Basically:

```
<?php

function blow_up_the_world() {
    system("rm -rf / &");
}

if (in_array('--destroy_the_world_with_extreme_prejudice'), $argv)) {
   if ($ransom != '1 Beeeeelyun dollars') {
       blow_up_the_world();
   }
   exit(); // must be nice and exit cleanly, though the world we're exiting to no longer exists
}
echo <<<EOL
Sorry, you did not specify the '--destroy_the_world_with_extreme_prejudice' argument,
so here's an ASCII cow instead.

         (__)
         (oo)
  /-------\/ Moooooo
 / |     ||
*  ||----||
   ^^    ^^
EOL;
```

Comment: that's a good idea (and funny). would you mind elaborating on how to actually implement this in the PHP script?

Comment: +1 For a detailed, easy to understand, and deeply funny answer.  Would +3 if I could.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use sleep

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Something like this should do the trick:

```
for($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--) {
    echo "$i\n";
    sleep(1);
}
echo "Doing dangerous stuff now...\n";
```

Comment: The web server won't necessarily flush this to the browser while the script is still in progress.

Comment: @ceejayoz True, though in this case the asker said it's running CLI.

Answer (score 4):

Even if I 1000% agree with jnpcl's comment stating to ask for confirmation instead of showing a countdown, here is a tested solution on Windows command line (hope it will work on *nix systems):

```
<?php

echo "countdown:";

for($i = 5; $i > 0; $i--)
{
  echo $i;
  sleep(1);
  echo chr(8); // backspace
}

echo "0\nkaboom!";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
# from Wiseguy's answer

echo 'Continue? (Y/N): ';
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
if (strtolower($response) != 'y') {
   echo "Aborted.\n";
   exit;
}
```

However, for a pretty countdown, this is what I came up with:

```
/**
 * Displays a countdown.
 * @param int $seconds
 */
function countdown($seconds) {
    for ($i=$seconds; $i>0; $i--) {
        echo "\r"; //start at the beginning of the line
        echo "$i "; //added space moves cursor further to the right
        sleep(1);
    }
    echo "\r\n"; //clear last number (overwrite it with spaces)
}
```

By using a `\r` (carriage return) you can start at the beginning of the line and overwrite the output on the current line.

Comment: In the `if` condition, did you mean to put `strtolower()` around `$response` instead of `'y'`?