# Interactive shell using PHP

Tags: php, shell, interactive

Is it possible to create an interactive shell, using PHP alone?

I mean something like you have with databases, [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), etc. If it is, how?

Comment: Related: *[How to use the PHP interactive shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767606/how-to-use-the-php-interactive-shell)*

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. In order to be interactive, the program must be able to wait for and read in user input from *[stdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin))*. In PHP, you can read from *stdin* by opening a file descriptor to [`'php://stdin'`](http://php.net/stdin). Taken from [an answer to different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638677/php-5-second-countdown-cli-not-javascript/5639075#5639075), here's an example of an interactive user prompt in PHP (when run from the command line, of course):

```
echo "Continue? (Y/N) - ";

$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$response = fgetc($stdin);
if ($response != 'Y') {
   echo "Aborted.\n";
   exit;
}
```

Of course, to get a full line of input rather than a single character, you'd need [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) instead of [`fgetc()`](http://php.net/fgetc). Depending what your program/shell will do, the whole program might be structured as one big continuous loop. Hopefully that gives you an idea how to get started. If you wanted to get *really* fancy (CLI pseudo-GUI), you could [use ncurses](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1083).

Answer (score 35):

Since this question has been asked and answered, a *better* solution has been added to PHP. In all recent PHP versions, at least PHP 5.4, you can easily get user input as so:

```
$input = fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: Works if I strip whitespace: `$input = rtrim(fgets(STDIN)); `

Comment: What version of PHP does this apply to?

Comment: @AaronWallentine: I've been using it since at least PHP 5.4. Note that **all** current PHP versions support `fgets(STDIN)` now.

Answer (score 6):

The way I understand your question you just want the PHP interpreter to run on the command line so you that it will evaluate any PHP code that you type. I use that feature of Python all the time to test code snippets. In which case I believe the answer you are looking for is to execute (from the command line):

```
php -a
```

Assuming PHP is in your path this will drop you in to the PHP interpreter, like it does on mine:

```
php -a

Interactive shell

php >
```

From there you can start to evaluate arbitrary PHP expressions and see the results:

```
php > $a = 'abcdef';
php > echo strlen($a);
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an expanded take on this. I've added an `isCLI()` check in case you're run your script both in CLI and on a web server. Otherwise the server could loop using my function. This solution will prompt the user, check the input, and re-prompt the user for fixed input if necessary.

I [rtrim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) the input, because if the user uses return to submit their entry, that may be appended to the entry. Validation is not necessary; just don't pass a function in that case.

```
function isCLI() {
    return (php_sapi_name() === 'cli' OR defined('STDIN'));
}

function userPrompt($message, $validator=null) {
    if (!isCLI()) 
        return null;

    print($message);
    $handle = fopen ('php://stdin','r');
    $line = rtrim(fgets($handle), "\r\n");

    if (is_callable($validator) && !call_user_func($validator, $line)) {
        print("Invalid Entry.\r\n");
        return userPrompt($message, $validator);
    } else {
        print("Continuing...\r\n");
        return $line;
    }
}

// Example =====================

function validateSetLangCode($str) {
    return preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9]{3}-[A-Z]{2}$/", $str);
}

$code = userPrompt("Please enter the set / language codes. Use the format 'SET-EN', where SET is the three-letter set code and EN is the two-letter lang code. \r\n", 'validateSetLangCode') ?: 'SET-EN';
var_dump($code);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since PHP has a built-in **Unix-only** function `readline()` to do exactly that, note:

We can use and hold the result of `readline` in a variable.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    $user = readline("List dir [l] | Say hello [h] | exit [q]: ");

    if ($user === "l"){ system("ls"); }

    if ($user === "h"){ echo "Hello!"; }

    if ($user === "q"){ exit; }

    echo "\nThanks!";
```

**Example output:**

`l` ls result

`h` «hello»

`q` exit

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> exit.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> with empty input, continue to the next sequence. «Thanks». `$user` is defined and empty, no error.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> with some input: No action. Still waiting for input.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> Continue and take the current input in `$user`.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> Continue and take the current input in `$user`, same behavior as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>.

`Return` continue to the next sequence «Thanks». `$user` can stay empty, no error.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> may be used to cancel a loop and move to the top one. `$user` will be unset if the var is not defined in this scope.

Depending input, we can define empty values using`!empty` or do more surgical testings (the readline response can be many chars).

`$user` can be tested with `!isset` if not yet *asked*.

There is also the built-in `readline_add_history()` to store the user input into an object, where values can be retrieved directly by their name (nice for code clarity):

```
readline_add_history($user);
print_r(readline_list_history());
print_r(readline_user());
```

It is very useful to build real complex stuffs!

See how to [catch and send POSIX signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58260848/2494754).

[PHP function readline()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the interactive shell to process PHP commands, one example is [phpsh](http://www.phpsh.org/) which was apparently created at Facebook, but it is written in Python.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I want create the shell using PHP, as you stated.

Answer (score 1):

I know the questioner didn't want the second option, but for those that wanted the second option as I did, in addition to `phpsh`, PHP also has its [own shell](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php):

Just run `php -a`.

Comment: Note that it won't work as intended in Windows (in there you can only type a file's contents and hit `Ctrl`+`Z` `Enter`). Quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Check out *[Sheldon](https://github.com/shaneharter/sheldon)*.

It's pretty easy to get started. It includes [Symfony 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony#Releases) and [Zend Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminas) libraries that do a lot of the basic console I/O work and gives you a higher-level abstraction built around [command objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) (with regex routes) and Contexts (which hold immutable state).

One of the things I love is that "out of the box", your application can run as either an interactive shell, or as a standard script that you can run from the command line, specify a command, pass any arguments, and when the command is finished the application exits.

Comment: The beauty of OSS -- send me a PR @ViniciusMonteiro :)

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary, because in the Github's page says is required PHP PCNTL Extension and the PHP's manual says this extension is not available on Windows