# How to run 2 dependent shell commands by php

Tags: php, shell

i have 2 shell commands and i want to exec in php the first command that act like an application and stay into it and exec another command there (in this application).

i write in my shell:  `wpa_cli`
and get the result:

```
 Interactive mode
    >
```

now i can write commands in that software, like:

```
   Interactive mode
    > status
```

and get the result:

```
 wpa_state=DISCONNECTED
    p2p_device_address=34:b1:f7:1f:2d:bb
    address=34:b1:f7:1f:2d:bb
    >
```

my problem is that i want to do that outside the shell by php.

how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is similar to this [interactive shell using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5794578/4381432), but it requires execution of PHP script in terminal, which you don't want.

So, in this case, you can use any of these php functions: `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system` or `passthru` and run both `wpa_cli status` commands together, you will get the required result.

e.g. run the following script in your php file and see the output,

```
echo '<pre>'. shell_exec('wpa_cli status') .'</pre>';
```

You can also use [PHP Ajax Shell](https://gist.github.com/LAV45/1966d2ba3c73548b0ee1) or similar scripts to execute your commands and get response on the same page without reloading it.