# PHP loop listen for user input

Tags: php, while-loop, readline

I have a PHP script that run on console.

```
while(1) {
 doStuff();
 sleep(2);
}
```

I need to accept input from the console. I don't want loop stop each time and wait for me to input some text.

What i want is while loop continue as normal, if i type something in console, php script able to read that text and update some variable.

Can this be done ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interactive shell using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794030/interactive-shell-using-php)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with non-blocking I/O. You'll need the [`stream_set_blocking`](http://php.net/stream_set_blocking) method and [`stream_select`](http://php.net/stream_select):

```
stream_set_blocking(STDIN, FALSE);

while (1) {
    doStuff();

    $readStreams = [STDIN];
    $timeout = 2;

    // stream_select will block for $timeout seconds OR until STDIN
    // contains some data to read.
    $numberOfStreamsWithData = stream_select(
        $readStreams,
        $writeStreams = [],
        $except = [],
        $timeout
    );

    if ($numberOfStreamsWithData > 0) {
        $userInput = fgets(STDIN);

        // process $userInput as you see fit
    } else {
        // no user input; repeat loop as normal
    }
}
```