# Symfony Command that keeps listening for stream input and updates screen information

Tags: symfony

I have a plan of writing a small command line tool that does the following (without getting into details):

- Listen for input stream (a tail of some files)
- Parse incoming data and update screen information real-time (like the `top` command does for example)

Untill the application is being quited (CTLR + C) it will be updating (not appending!) the information on the screen.

I prefer to work with the [Symfony console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console).

Since they have for example the [progress-bar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html) I expect it to be doable, since the progress-bar does update the screen. (However, I don't need an actual progressbar).

Keep listening for an input stream and keep updating when information comes in is something I am not sure about to be possible in this manner.

I can't find enough information on how to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible and what components I would need to:

- Listen for input stream and trigger an event when information comes in
- Update screen information

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:**

For now I built the tool without using any framework. I wrote it myself by using  [this "Listening for incoming streams" example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34820663/2459026) and [this "setting cursor position" example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5265440/2459026) (and ofcourse [this referenced overview of commands](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)).

However I still would like to know whether and how this would be possible using Symfony's console components.